# Dynamically create WIX files without having to edit the wix files manually

Tags: windows, automation, wix, wix3

Suppose you release the next version of your software, you will have to *manually* update your WIX files to remove obsolete files and add new files, etc.

My use case is as simple as "recursively add the files under /sample/path in the user target C:\Program Files\MyApp".

Is there a program that does this sort of automation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For WiX v3 (and a free solution), look at heat.exe. If you have more advanced harvesting needs, there is a [commercial option from FireGiant](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/harvesting/)**.

** Disclaimer: I am the benevolent dictator of the WiX Toolset *and* CEO of FireGiant. We contribute to the open source project and provide commercial solutions around the project. Pick what works best for you.

Answer (score 4):

If Heat doesn't meet your needs, you may want to look at [Paraffin](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/07/09/paraffin-3-13-and-an-ask-for-help.aspx) by John Robbins.

Answer (score 3):

For Wix 2 there was a tool called Mallow that did this. It was freeware and I got the source somewhere. This functionality may also be available in Heat.exe at this point, but I am not sure.

It also seems some guys in the Wix community are experimenting with a sort of automatic scanner feature where you can put files in a pre-defined release location and new msi files are continually created - ala "continuous integration".

Are you looking to do this for a lot of packages, or just for one or a few ones? Let me know the scope and I can send you the Mallow code, or dig up links for the "continuous integration" oriented solutions.

Comment: As of now, only a few (few = 1-3). But in future, I would like this to be a general feature as well. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430497/application-to-generate-installers-for-linux-windows-and-macosx-from-a-single-co

Comment: It's looks like you're in luck, someone else appears to have updated Mallow to Wix 3: http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/mallow-for-wix-v3.html

Comment: I know Christopher Painter has been working on automating wix builds, but I am out of date with regards to status. His blog is here: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use heat.exe as Rob stated already (i think he knows since he is the man behind), or you can write a simple harvester script, that evaluate the wix-script as pre-compile action of the wix-project. We used a vbscript for that since heat did not suit our problems, cause of different files, different directories, etc.

Answer (score 1):

WixEdit has an import folder function that can grab the entire contents of a folder and turn it into Directory/Component/File nodes.